# Notification Action button to pass info to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have created a big view style notification in a service

I intend to put a button that will pass some info back to the activity but it seems the activity just can't get the extras I set before.

Here's the code that I used to show the notification:

```
public class TestService extends Service {
...
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    showNotification();
}
private void showNotification() {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
            new Intent(this, TestActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent discardIntent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
    discardIntent.putExtra("piAction", "discard");
    PendingIntent piDiscard = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, discardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Test Notification");
    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.content_discard, "Discard", piDiscard);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Test service is running"));

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
} 
...  

}
```

And here's the activity that will catch the info sent by the button in notification

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

...
@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("Activity Resume", "onResume");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "extras not null");
            if (extras.containsKey("piAction")) {
                Log.i("Intent Received", "piAction");

            }
        }
}
...
}
```

---

Please note, when launching `TestActivity`, it will also start `TestService`. What I intend to do is when the `discard` button inside the notification is clicked, it will pass the previously put extra back to `TestActivity`. However, after a few tests, I found `TestActivity` can be launched successfully, but it can't get the extras I set before.

So where's the possible problems in my code?

If you require any other details, please state in the comment, I'll update my question with those details accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had face same type of problem when I was passing string from my notification to my launching activity to solve that 
1) take a one String e.g. public String temp field in your application extended class 
now instead of this

```
discardIntent.putExtra("piAction", "discard");
```

use this

```
YourApplication app = (YourApplication)getApplicationContext();
    app.temp = "discard";
```

in your activity 
instead of this

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "extras not null");
            if (extras.containsKey("piAction")) {
                Log.i("Intent Received", "piAction");

            }
        }
```

get your piAction status from YourApplication

```
YourApplication app = (YourApplication)getApplicationContext();
String stringFromNotification = app.temp;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Will it work if my service is running and the activity is in the background (more specifically, `onPause()`)?